# Getting null value of asp.net radiobuttonlist listitem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this RadioButtonList

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="loanTypeCheck" CssClass="pull-right" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Cash" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;Cash&nbsp;&nbsp;"/>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Non-Cash" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;Non-Cash&nbsp;&nbsp;" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="Dharauti" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;Dharauti&nbsp;&nbsp;" />                           
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And in Code Behind in my save button event

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsFormValidForSave())
        {
            var loanReceipt = GetLoanReceiptFromForm();
            var transactionsDetails = new List<TransactionDetail>();
            var loantypeCheck = loanTypeCheck.SelectedValue;
            //if (IsCashReceipt)
            if (loantypeCheck == "Cash")
            {
                var transaction = new Transaction()
                {
                    AuditUserId = UserId,
                    OfficeId = OfficeId,
                    VerificationStatusId = 0,
                    BookName = EverestEnums.TransactionBookName.LoanReceipt,
                    BookNameString = EverestEnums.TransactionBookName.LoanReceipt.ToString(),
                    TranDateString = DateConversion.GetCurrentServerDate().ToString(),
                    ValueDateString = ValueDateControl.ValueDateAd.ToString(),
                    TellerId = UserId,
                    TotalAmount = SubmittedAmountTextBox.Text.ToDecimal(),
                    ValueDate = ValueDateControl.ValueDateAd,
                    TranDate = DateConversion.GetCurrentServerDate(),
                };
```

i am getting null value for the radio button.Am i missing something?

Comment: The `RadioButtonList` `loanTypeCheck` is `null` at `loanTypeCheck.SelectedValue`? You have to tell us more since that is normally not posssible. Where do you try to read the `SelectedValue` and where is the list declared?

Comment: Damn... because I had no coffee yet and misread the question and flagged it mistakenly. I'm sorry!

Comment: @TimSchmelter I edited my question sir.

Comment: This thing was creating the problem..I wanted to disable the other two radio button the moment one of them is selected..var checkedValue = $(this).filter(':checked').val();
            $("#<%=loanTypeCheck.ClientID %>").find('input').prop('disabled', true);   i commented this js code and i got the value..

Comment: Like Tim said, you need to tell us a little more. Where is the RadioButtonList declared? Is it contained within something else, such as a GridView?

Comment: @j.f. Thanks for going through my question sir..the problem was with my js code.i wanted to disable the other two when one of them is selected.And that sent the null value.